# Arraylist to push dynamic table row using Selenium,TestNG,java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[image]

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lnkLogin")).click();

WebElement  cmp = driver.findElement(By.id("txtCompanySearch"));
cmp.sendKeys("Demo Company");

driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr[5]/td")).get(0).click();
```

This code above worked for me but it works as static `xpath` index for selecting,
but I want to get all rows which match my `sendKeys` value.

I have tried this but this is not working

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
By elems = By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr");
WebElement select = driver.findElement(elems);
List<WebElement> matches = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr"));
List<String> currentVals = new ArrayList<>();
for (WebElement match : matches) {
    currentVals.add(match.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `.` in `xpath` you are using current context, so

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr"));
List<WebElement> matches = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr"));
```

Is the equivalent of

```
List<WebElement> matches = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr"));
```

Basically you are looking for an element which is a child of itself. Just locate the elements directly

```
By elems = By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr");
List<WebElement> matches = driver.findElements(elems));
```

Comment: okay after getting match as there is multiple match shoen in image i want to select the one with index 0 driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr['+index+']/td")).click();

Comment: @Rao Just click on the first element of the list `matches.get(0).click();`

Comment: `By elems = By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr");
  WebElement select = driver.findElement(elems);
  List<WebElement> matches = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"TenantTBL\"]/tbody/tr"));
  matches.get(0).click();` please verify this i didnt worked

Comment: yes , but i have updated it can u please verify because it isnt working ... thanks

Comment: @Rao I don't know what you changed, but the basic problem still exists. I gave the source of the problem and the solution in my answer. If you want to try something else its up to you, but I can't check everything you want to try.